# Defining Input length boundaries using RegEx

Tags: regex

I need to use a RegEx to set an upper boundry for the length of an input string.

Its been ages since I used RegEx so any help would be good. :)

Comment: What exactly are you talking about? What kind of field? What technology? Is it HTML?

Comment: Is it an input type="text" field?

Comment: There is no need whatsoever to use a regex to validate the length of a string.

Comment: @karim79: Why not? You don't know the situation or the technology being used. Maybe there's some validator that accepts a regex?

Comment: Please note karim79, i said "I need to use a RegEx" that implies that I DO need to use a RegEx.

Comment: What *are* the circumstances that force you to use a regex?

Comment: I am using a research language which only accepts regex as validation.

Comment: Since using a regex to enforce a maximum string length is quite inefficient not to mention harder to read and easier to get wrong, you should probably mention the very relevant fact in an edit to your question - that would make the question less likely to mislead a novice and people less likely to downvote your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^.{,5}$
```

The ^ and $ make it check the entire string. {,5} is maximum of five.

Answer (score 4):

If you want max 10 characters:

```
^.{,10}$
```